# How to model noexcept, override, final or any further C++ specifier in Visual Paradigm?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-paradigm

**Scenario:**

I am creating the design for a software in UML2, using Visual Paradigm as a tool. The idea is to be as close as possible of the C++11 language, for code generation and documentation.

**Current state of the art:**

In Visual-Paradigm, for C++ special specifiers, I followed the next steps (VP 12):

- Windows->Configuration->Configure Programming Language
- Selected C++ and Accept (Ok).

[image]

Any function in a class can now be set to virtual or const by:

- right-click -> Code details ->

[image]

But, I cannot found C++11 details, so I wonder if there is a way to add them or not.

**Question**

My question is: **Is it a way to add those specifiers to code detail?**

An other alternative would be to use stereotypes, but the result is not as good, specially for code generation.

Comment: Me, I'd just do a file-content string search through appdata, user data, and the program install directory for `__sealed` or `Return type const` to see where the existing config data is hiding.  If that fails, look for utf-16 variants.

Comment: I searched into user appData (workspace) and program install directory without results. What do you mean by "look for utf-16 variants"?
I found the file with language data types in the workspace, but nothing about code details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual paradigm has no support for C++11, so it is not possible currently.

From the answer from the VPP support, it seem they have this feature as an already planned feature, so we could expect this in following version (14?).

Until then, the best alternative I found is just to set a stereotype and manage it manually.